# Flutter: Theme not applied to Text Widget

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to make a custom theme that is applied to only the children of that theme.

However when I run the app, the Text widget that displays "hello" is still blue. I want to make it yellow.

Can anyone show me where i'm going wrong?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          brightness: Brightness.dark,
          primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
          accentColor: Colors.cyan[600],
          textTheme: TextTheme(body1: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Theme(
                data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                    textTheme:
                        TextTheme(body1: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellow))),
                child: Text("hello"))));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To theme a `Text` you need to assign the value to `style` property

```
Text("Hello", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1)
```

Make sure to use the correct `context` when doing `Theme.of(context)`. You need a `context` that is a child of your new `Theme`.

You'll need to do the following :

```
 Theme(
     child: Builder(
       builder: (context) {
         return Text("Hello", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1);
       }
     )
  )
```

Comment: Interesting ! but how to change font size ?

Comment: @JohnJoe Use ```copyWith``` to set additional properties ```style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1!.copyWith(fontSize: 20)```.

Answer (score 10):

This is another way, because sometimes it's more convenient to override the default style

**Text widget:**

> If the `style` argument is null, the text will use the style from the
>   closest enclosing `DefaultTextStyle`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final DefaultTextStyle defaultTextStyle = DefaultTextStyle.of(context);
    TextStyle effectiveTextStyle = style;
    if (style == null || style.inherit)
      effectiveTextStyle = defaultTextStyle.style.merge(style);
```

---

So, if you want to override the default style for the `Text` widget (when you do not pass the `style` property), you need to use the `DefaultTextStyle` widget

```
return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: Text(widget.title),
    ),
    body: Center(
        child: DefaultTextStyle(
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.body1.copyWith(color: Colors.yellow), 
          child: Text("hello"))
        )
);
```

### [image: DefaultTextStyle]

`MaterialApp` uses its `TextStyle` as its `DefaultTextStyle` to encourage developers to be intentional about their `DefaultTextStyle`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, since the author clearly showed the intent to override the default style for a single child instead of set the theme on that child.

Answer (score 3):

Latest Flutter Release mark `body1` has deprecated, so now we can use `bodyText2`:

```
Text("My Text", style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2)
```

**New params(Right ones are new)**

```
body2 => bodyText1;
body1 => bodyText2;
```

Answer (score 0):

as soon as use text theme in flutter why as soon as relies app hidden all text my app as soon as click on button back give me solve

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).